# Error: process didn't exit successfully: `\target\debug\decalang.exe main.rs` (exit code: 1)

Tags: rust

I made an interpreted programming language in rust. I used https://www.repl.it as ide to create it then I downloaded my work on my desktop to test it on vscode. But then when I ran the src/main.rs file, I got a bunch of errors but the project was working fine on replit.

Here is the github of the project : https://github.com/TheSandDog/decalang

And my repl : https://replit.com/@Eti011/decalang?v=1

I used the command cargo run main.rs to execute the file. I also tried to change the code and execute other files to see.

Comment: The problem is you're not using your own program correctly!  When you say `cargo run main.rs` You're asking your interpreter to run a Rust program, which of course it does not understand.  If you do `cargo run main.deca` then it works fine.

Comment: As a side note, I would encourage you to get rid of the ANSI escape sequences that clear the screen.  That's annoying to command-line users.

Comment: Where did you copy this from?  You didn't write all of this in replit, but there's no credit in any of the source code.

Comment: I actually used replit's chat integrated ai to code the program. Thats why im a bit confused But what I really don't understand is that in replit when i ran `cargo run main.rs` it was working and the shell was working but outside of replit i can only do `cargo run main.deca` without errors thats what im trying to figure out @TimRoberts

Comment: Finally fixed i only need to write `cargo run` to open the shell and `cargo run main.deca` for executing the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to use `cargo run` command and not `cargo run /src/main.rs` to run the shell